# Can an application bundle add items to the PATH?

Tags: macos

I want to make an OSX application bundle that installs a command-line tool. Is this possible, and if so, how? [The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/GeneralPurposeKeys.html) make it sound like the keys `APInstallerURL` and `APFiles` in `info.plist` can be used for this, but they don't make it clear how.

Answer (score 0):

I would just have the app:

- First, check if the executable is already installed (e.g. check the return code of `which yourExecutable`)
- If not installed, copy the executable to `/usr/local/bin/`, or somewhere else (your pick)
- If not copied to `/usr/local/bin/`, add the executable's location to the user's $PATH (add the following line to the end of their `~/.bash_profile`: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/executable`)

If the application bundle is exclusively for installing the tool, you could even do all this in AppleScript.

Comment: The problem is that this has the same downside as `.pkg` files; the file can't be uninstalled automatically.

Comment: Unless you include an uninstaller to reverse the process   : )